# issues rotating a matrix (openGL/glm)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

i've been creating a basic gui recently, and i'm trying to give the user the ability to rotate a shape/image/sprite. however, when i use glm::rotate to attempt to change the model matrix i get some unexpected results. the transformed shape changes dimensions, rotates way too far, and also rotates about a seemingly random point.

shader code:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 pos;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos.x, pos.y, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

rotation code:

```
m_modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
m_modelMatrix = glm::rotate(m_modelMatrix, 45.f, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1);
```

view and projection setup

```
glm::mat4 proj = glm::mat4(1.0f);
glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(53.f), 1.f, 0.1f, 100.f);
view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
```

everything is in 2d.

Comment: Degrees are usually specified with radians, `45.f` is  a huge value.

Comment: yes, sorry, i had meant to write glm::radians(45.f). either way, though, it still does not work.

Comment: You have to use a projection matrix, which takes care of the aspect ratio of the viewport. Furthermore note, that the object is rotated around (0, 0).

Comment: i do in fact have a projection matrix, as well as a view matrix.

Comment: @cummiesinmytummy Where is the projection matrix? `gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(pos.xy, 1.0, 1.0)`?

Comment: yes, that is precisely what my vertex shader looks like. i added it after you mentioned i needed one.

Comment: @cummiesinmytummy Please update the question with the current code and show how the projection matrix is set up.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please be sure to provide a [mcve] to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

I assume that you already have a setup with a projection and view matrix, like you pointed out in the comments. It should look like this,

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 pos;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos.x, pos.y, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

the projection matrix should have been created with

```
glm::ortho( ... );
```

or

```
glm::perspective( ... );
```

and the view matrix should have been created with

```
glm::lookAt( ... );
```

as described in https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00245.html.
If further explanation is required, I advise you to look at https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems as a reference.

I also assume that the problem originates from previous transformations and how this rotation is used to modify an existing model matrix. E.g. the problem only occurs when you have specified a model matrix other than the identity matrix.

When you create the model matrix, you have to make sure that you use the correct order of multiplication:

```
glm::mat4 translation = ... ;
glm::mat4 rotation = ... ;
glm::mat4 scale = ... ;
glm::mat4 model = translation * rotation * scale;
```

Since you will multiply a vector from the right hand side to the model matrix, this order guarantees you that no distortions will occur. The vector will be scaled first, then rotated and finally translated.

When you try to rotate the model matrix with,

```
glm::rotate(model, angle, axis);
```

you essentially multiply the rotation matrix from the right hand side and break the multiplication order of the model matrix.

```
model * rotation_from_user_input
= translation * rotation * scale * rotation_from_user_input
```

You would have to change the rotation of the model matrix like this

```
rotation *= rotation_from_user_input;
```

and then update the model matrix itself to fix the distortions.

```
model = translation * rotation * scale;
```

Comment: but in this case, i am not translating nor scaling the matrix at all. i also don't believe this is an error regarding previous transformations applied to the model matrix because just before i rotate it i wrote: `m_modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);` the way i rotate it is also equivalent to how it is done here: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations

Comment: @cummiesinmytummy I am having trouble finding the cause of the problems in your code. Could you update your question so that it matches your actual vertex shader with projection matrix and all? It would also help to see the application code (e.g. rendering loop).

Comment: sure thing. it's updated now.

Comment: I like your explanation: it's to the point.

Comment: @cummiesinmytummy maybe this is a problem with the resolution.
I can see that the screen ratio of your projection matrix is 1:1.
The second parameter in the following function call
`glm::perspective(glm::radians(53.f), 1.f, 0.1f, 100.f);`

If you have a window ratio other than 1:1 (16:9 for example), the results will be distorted.